# Shade area between a straight line and plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have searched the web thoroughly but still found no exact solution to this. I need to shade the intersecting area above the straight line and below the plot in MATLAB.

[image]

I need to shade the area above the threshold at 110 and under the plot.

Comment: This is a workaround but maybe just food for thought. Have you considered drawing a bunch of vertical lines. If they are close enough together you might get the same visual effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a way using `area` :

```
% generate "data"
    x=1:100;
    y1=0.5*ones(100,1);
    y2=exp(-(x(:)-50).^2/500).^.5+0.1*rand(100,1);

% do the plot

    h=area([y1(:) , (y2(:)-y1(:)).* (y2(:)>y1(:)) ]);
    h(1).FaceColor=[1 1 1];
    h(2).FaceColor=[0 0 1 ];
    hold on;

    plot(x,y2,'b',x,y1,'r');
```

[image]